# Proxmox - migration fails with exit code 255

Tags: proxmox

Attempting to migrate a container between Proxmox nodes failed saying the following command failed with exit code 255:

```
TASK ERROR: command '/usr/bin/ssh -e none -o 'BatchMode=yes' -o 'HostKeyAlias=violet' root@172.20.20.1 pvecm mtunnel -migration_network 172.20.20.1/16 -get_migration_ip' failed: exit code 255
```

Running the command manually shows the given error message:

```
could not get migration ip: multiple, different, IP address configured for network 172.20.20.1/16
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had a second interface on the target host configured on the same network (`eno1` had `172.20.0.1` and `eno3` had `172.20.20.3`, e.g.). Removing/disabling one of these interfaces resolved the issue.